# Javascript recursion starts twice randomly

Tags: javascript, recursion, web-scraping, request, cheerio

I've run into a weird problem when using recursion to scrap a web page. Here's the code

```
var baseUrl     = "url.to.search", 
formData    = []; //array that contains the items to be scraped

function startSearch(){
    if(formData.length == 0){
        endOfSearch();
    } else{

        //here to get the url to start scrapping and then jump to the next one
        scrapeData(searchUrl);
    }
}

function scrapeData(url) {
    console.log(url);

    if (!url){  
        formData.splice(0,1);
        startSearch();
    } else{
        var user = {};

        request(url, function (err, resp, body) {
            var $ = cheerio.load(body), nextUrl = null;
            //scrapping of the page
            scrapeData(/*nextUrl goes here*/);  
        });
    }   
}

function endOfSearch() {
    res.send("finished!");
}

startSearch();
```

I can't figure why it would do something like this when I console.log all the urls that are called

[image]

As you can see, it gets called again in the middle of the recursion, starting the same cycle with the first item. It shouldn't be possible, as it startSearch isn't called more than once. Am I doing something wrong here?

thanks!
Edit 1: corrected the code to delete the "queries" and change it with formData where it should be used.

Comment: `if (!url){ startSearch(queries); }` this doesn't look right. `queries` will be undefined.

Comment: Logic is weird you would call startSearch when you are done.... But add log lines to see why it is being triggered again. Maybe some of the logic you are not showing is the cause?

Comment: Yeah, should call the formData which is global, and when no url is found, splice it so it can call startSearch() with the next element on the list (it takes the first element to build the url to start scrapping). I corrected the code btw.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the answer. Apart from the recursion being not so well written (I've corrected it) everything was wraped insied an app.get request. Because it didn't finish in a set time, the browser (Chrome) would refresh the page, causing the app.get to start again. Thanks for the help!